# Display jquery dialog by pressing a button ( no input )

Tags: jquery

I try to show jquery dialog by clicking the Delete button ( which also serves to erase data if the user than in the dialog ), but when I press the Delete dialog then disappears after the second and screen pops .
I'd love someone to help me because I really green in jquery
And how to check user code approved in dialog
Thank you :)

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").hide();
            $("#but_Delete").click(function () {
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 250,
                    width: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Delete ": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        },
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".selector").dialog({
                    closeOnEscape: false

                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

```html
   <asp:Button ID="but_Delete"  UseSubmitBehavior="false"   runat="server" Height="26px" OnClick="but_Delete_Click"  Text="מחק" Width="93px" />
```

```
protected void but_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
                      if (TextBox_campeny.Text != null || TextBox_Addres.Text != null || TextBox_tel.Text != null)
                {                 
                        con.Open();
                        string id = tb.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from tbl_Customer where Id='" + id + "'", con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                 
                        Response.Write("הרשומה נמחקה בהצלחה!");
                        con.Close();
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd_u = new SqlCommand("Delete from tbl_Users where IdCustomer='" + id + "'", con);
                        SqlDataAdapter dac = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_u);
                        dac.Fill(tb);
                        if (butuc == 1)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(tb.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 1)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {                                
                                    bind();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (tb.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 == i)
                                    {
                                        i--;
                                        bind();
                                    }
                                    else
                                        bind();                                  
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Empty_Textbox();
                                but_Delete.Enabled = false;
                            }

                        }
                    }
               }                                    
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: please fix your code snippet... it is cut half way through

Answer (score 0):

for these kind of things i would highly recommend you to use ready made frameworks that give you these kinds of functionality "for free"...
so especially if you're green and want quick results i would recommend using bootstrap 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals (this handles modals for exactly same stuff you are looking for)
or semantic ui
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html